# Symfony 2. Doesn't work usort()

Tags: php, symfony, usort

guys! I need help. Usort() doesn't work in symfony2 class.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{   ...
 /**
 * @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard")
 */

public function dashboard()
{
```

SQL Query:

```
    /** @var \MyBundle\Entity\User $user */
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->find($this->getUser()->getId());
    /** @var \MyBundle\Entity\Event[] $events */
    $events = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Event')
        ->findBy(['creator' => $user->getId()]);
```

Data Arrays:

```
$allEvents = [];        
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $allEvents[] = $event;
    }
    foreach ($user->getEvents() as $event) {
        $allEvents[] = $event;
    }
```

Result to twig:

```
    return $this->render(
        'MyBundle:User:dashboard.html.twig',
        [ 'allEvents' => usort($allEvents, function( $a, $b )
            { if ( $a["schedule"] == $b["schedule"] )
                { return 0; }
                else
                { return ( $a["schedule"] < $b["schedule"] ) ? -1 : 1; }
            }),
```

*code continuation...*

What's wrong?

Comment: `usort()` returns TRUE on success and FALSE otherwise.

Comment: In the browser: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MyBundle\Entity\Event as array in ...\Controller\UserController.php on line 113" : { if ( $a["schedule"] == $b["schedule"] )

Comment: usort() works perfectly well, but only on __arrays__. The error is telling you exactly what's wrong, you're trying to use usort() on something that isn't an array, to whit, an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rizier123 says, `usort()` [returns a boolean](https://secure.php.net/usort).

So try this:

```
// First, sort the array
usort($allEvents, function($a, $b) { // $a and $b are instances of MyBundle\Entity\Event
    // this depends on your object, just call the right function
    if ($a->getSchedule() == $b->getSchedule()) {
        return 0;
    }

    return $a->getSchedule() < $b->getSchedule() ? -1 : 1;
});

// Then, use the sorted array in your template
return $this->render('MyBundle:User:dashboard.html.twig', [
    'allEvents' => $allEvents,
]);
```